# How to delay a function definition in NestList

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have a code like this. The algorithm is that the original number, `2`, has some chance to either be constant `3` or to be 10 times multiple. And whatever the iteration result is, that result will again either become constant `3` or 10 times multiple. Repeated it again and again. However, the random number generated by `RandomInteger[3]` is fixed after the first evaluation, this is not I want. How to delay the function definition (somewhat like `SetDelayed`) which is inside the `NestList`'s first argument?

```
NestList[If[RandomInteger[3]== 1, 3 &, 10*# &], 2, 20]
(*possible outcome: {2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}*)
```

**Update:**

(My thoughts and self notes, not a question.) I think the reason that the correction of the code suggested by the answers would work is that a pure function was born to be a set-delayed kind function.
In other words, `Function[x,x+a]` is equivalent to a *set-delayed* function like `f[x_]:=x+a`. So only when the function is being called, `a` would be replaced by the current value of `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that must be repeatedly evaluated must be behind the `Function` symbol `&`. You can triple click the symbol to see how much that is.

```
NestList[If[RandomInteger[3] == 1, 3, 10 #] &, 2, 20]
```

Comment: So the `NestList` will evaluate its first arguement first, then apply it to the second arguement? If so, in general case, other than using pure function, how to prevent the the first argument of `NestList` from evaluating before applying to the second argument of `NestList`?

Comment: @Eric First question: Yes. Second question: The first argument (which should be a function) is evaluated but not called before it's applied to the second argument. When `If[RandomInteger[3] == 1, 3, 10 #] &` is evaluated the random function is held because its wrapped by `&`, so you don't need to prevent the first argument from evaluation.

Comment: So if I want to achieve the same effect, I can also consider explcitly define a function in a previous line. e.g. `myFunctionForNest[x_] := If[RandomInteger[3] == 1, 3, 10*x]
NestList[myFunctionForNest, 2, 20]`
But the result is {2,10,....}. I don't know why there arises a number `10`?

Comment: @Eric Retry after `Remove[myFunctionForNest, x]`. I can't reproduce it

Comment: Oh it success! I left some previous definition. Mistake. :) Now I understand it, thanks!